# Построение цепочки из прокси в Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Занимаюсь парсингом сайта через Selenium с корпоративного сервера, работающего из-под корпоративного прокси. Недавно получил бан на этом сайте. Решил построить цепочку из прокси.

Это можно сделать, например, с помощью такого когда:

```
import socket
import pyChainedProxy as socks #import pyChainedProxy
import requests

# Enable debugging
def DEBUG(msg):
    print (msg)

socks.DEBUG = DEBUG

# Configure a default chain
chain = [
    'http://****:****/',
    'http://****:****',
]
socks.setdefaultproxy() # Clear the default chain
#adding hops with proxies
for hop in chain:
    socks.adddefaultproxy(*socks.parseproxy(hop))

# Configure alternate routes (No proxy for localhost)
socks.setproxy('localhost', socks.PROXY_TYPE_NONE)
socks.setproxy('127.0.0.1', socks.PROXY_TYPE_NONE)

# Monkey Patching whole socket class (everything will be proxified)
rawsocket = socket.socket
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
# Everything will be proxied!

print ("Check IP After proxyfying:  ",requests.get(url))
```

При таком подходе получается достучаться до сайте через requests, однако через Selenium это сделать не получается.

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли это сделать через Selenium?

Мой код Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium_stealth import stealth

options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager' 
srvc = Service(***path_to_webdriver***) 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = srvc, options = options)

stealth(driver, languages=["en-US", "en"], vendor="Google Inc.", platform="Win32", webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.", renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine", fix_hairline=True)

driver.get(url)
```